# Laravel single blade file used for create and show

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

Is it possible and recommended that I have one lets say `form.blade.php` with html form file used for create new data and show existing data by ID.

I want to create this becouse file for insert and dispaly is the some. I want to avoid DRY.

**Example:** I have product categories, when I create a new category I need `create.blade.php` a file containing an html form. Now I want to use that same file to display the details of that category that will populate the fields in the fields by the given ID

**Controller**

```
   // Create 
   public function create()
   {
      return view('admin.category.form');
   }


  // Show
   public function show(Category $category)
   {
      $category = Category::find($category);

      return view('admin.category.form', [
          'category' => $category
      ]);
   }
```

Or is it better to make a separate file for insert and separet file for show?

Comment: Personally I'd call each method with its own blade file (`show.blade.php` and `create.blade.php`) and `@include` a `form.blade.php` in each of those.

Comment: @brombeer this is good for form.  I didn't know about this. Thanks i will try

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere when you want to use same blade file then you can write in your create method as

```
 public function create()
 {
    return view('admin.category.form',[
          'category' => new Category()
      ]);
 }
```